# Issue Saving setting and retrieving cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

from a url query I am trying to grab two variables and the values. **all_links** and **all_ers** My goal is to retrieve the values from the URL string, set a cookie and retrieve them when a user goes to a form on my site. I have done a browser inspect and I am not seeing any cookie. Also should I consider using javascript over jQuery cookie?

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js'></script>
<script>
// Parse the URL
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
// Give the URL parameters variable names
var all_links = getParameterByName('link1');
var all_ers = getParameterByName('link2');

// Set the cookies
$.cookie('link1', all_links);
$.cookie('link2', all_ers);

// Grab the cookie value and set the form field values
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=link1').val(all_links);
    $('input[name=link2').val(all_ers);
})
</script>
```

Comment: have you verified that getParameterByName is returning values?

Comment: The cookies should be set regardless if getParameterByName returns any value or not. Have you checked Developer tools -> Application -> Cookies (this is when using chrome)?

Comment: @Mathias yes that is where I checked and not cookie is listed

Comment: Do you get any errors @acctman? Asking because the cookies are properly set for me with the provided code.

Comment: @MathiasW we have an error ... Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cookie' of undefined at contact:512

Comment: Are you including jQuery? Your error sounds like `$` is undefined, which would indicate to me that jQuery is not being loaded properly.